# Lots of checkboxes to add to my RealmObject

Tags: android, database, realm

I use checkboxes a lot in my app and there is a screen where I have 3 different logical categories where the user might choose ( check ) one or more checkboxes.

Right now I have a RealmObject with more than 20 fields with each one having a value of zero if its not checked and a value of one if it is.

Is there a way to make more cohesive my database's table schema?

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from creating a separate class for each of your categories? If they contain different checkboxes they should be considered different types anyway? Also why use numbers for checkboxes, wouldn't a boolean be much more appropriate?

Comment: yes you are correct for both the classes for each category and for the boolean value. Thanks